# Why is this one playlist unable to be synced with iTunes Match?

Tags: itunes, icloud, itunes-match, playlist, smart-playlist

I have a smart playlist made up of the following rules:

[image: Collected Gym Music — Smart Playlist rules]

But it won't sync with my iCloud Music Library (formerly known as iTunes Match), giving the error:

[image]

Given that I have specifically selected `Media Kind is Music` and `iCloud Status is not Ineligible`, why does it insist that the playlist "includes other media kinds or songs that are not eligible"?

Im using iTunes version 12.3.044 (the latest version at time of posting this question).

Comment: Are all tracks in a format which iCloud Music can process (MP3 and AAC)? Also, does it sync if you untick the last three options?

Comment: All the tracks are actually in iCloud. And no, it seems I can't sync a playlist that references another playlist. Which is, I guess the answer to my question, but it's certainly not what the error message says. Sigh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the comment above by @patrix it seems the problem is that my playlist references another playlist, and it's simply that the error message that iTunes gives me is wrong.

[This Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31497/itunes-match-syncing-smart-playlists-that-reference-other-playlists?rq=1) has more information on the issue.