# Itunes smart Playlist with reference to Apple Music favorites won't sync to Iphone

Tags: itunes, icloud, iphone, apple-music, smart-playlist

I have created a Playlist (pl1) and favorited some of the tracks in it.
But because I want to filter (the heart symbol in Apple Music) **only the tracks which are favorited from pl1** I created a smart playlist with following settings:

- contained in **pl1** *AND*
- marked as **favorite**

My Problem now is that the new smart playlist won't sync over to my iPhone...
pl1 and the favorites sync normally and even the favorited tracks from pl1 show up in favorites on the iPhone but as I said the smart playlist won't show up.

I tried the following:

1. Restart the iPhone
2. Re-Enable Apple Music
3. Relogging from icloud
4. Recreating both pl1 and the smart playlist

I also found these two questions:

- [ITunes Match: syncing smart playlists that reference other
  playlists](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31497/itunes-match-syncing-smart-playlists-that-reference-other-playlists)
- [iTunes smart playlist not syncing to iPhone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/itunes-smart-playlist-not-syncing-to-iphone)

But the first one is about itunes match and the second one said that it worked again after some time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you are not able to sync Smart Playlists that contain a rule referencing another playlist with Apple Music tracks.

In some cases you may be able to get around this by making a normal playlist and putting Smart Playlists in that (for example my top 100 played tracks **and** my Loved tracks), but as you are trying to get just the intersection that wouldn't work.

Can only suggest giving Apple feedback at:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/itunesapp.html
- http://www.apple.com/feedback/apple-music.html

Comment: OMG. Why I can't reference songs from my simple playlist in my smart playlist with sync feature? This is insane.

Answer (score 0):

Although a Smart Playlist that contains a rule referencing another playlist cannot sync I have found a simple work around:

Create a normal playlist (this wil be the end result playlist that you are going to use) and from iTunes on your computer simply drag the smart playlist into this playlist. This adds the content from the Smart Playlist into the normal playlist - without any syncing issues.

This works for me and although it has the need for some manual implementation, it is minimal and in your case it should not be to big of a problem.

Comment: this is not smart playlist in the end, because you just create a normal playlist which doesn't have any rules. omg...